# Radare2 - How to scale panel height in visual panels mode?

Tags: radare2

Visual Panels Mode (`V!`):

I need more space (height) for `RegisterRefs` and less for `Registers` (its 50% blank anyway). How can i do that? I can move the vertical split with `H` and `L` but i couldn't find anything for the horizontal splits.

Comment: Sadly, this feature is not implemented yet. It's a work-in-progress and I hope you'll see the feature implemented in the next few weeks.

Comment: Even though this is already answered, this gitbook could help you out in the future https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/visual_mode/visual_panels.html

Answer (score 4):

I found a way! 
Press `w` you will enter in "Window mode" 
Use `hjkl` to move around panels and `HJKL` to resize then.
To quit "Window mode" press `q`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if there is an option for that. What you could do is to close `Registers` and some other frames that you do not use at the moment thus creating more space for the registers. To close the section, move to it with <kbd>TAB</kbd> and then close with <kbd>X</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, no persistent solution. Its all back to stock if you leave and re-enter the mode. Also, y-size gets spread evenly when y-split line is moved. Looks like there's currently no solution. I probably have to work more with the cmdline instead then.

Comment: or you can implement something like that and send a pull-request. Or suggest implementing something like this in the radare2 repo.